# Wifi not getting detected after upgrading to 14.04 [D-Link N 300 DSL-2750U]

Tags: 14.04, wireless, upgrade

I connected the ethernet cable and waited for additional drivers to show up, did not happen. Help needed urgently.

Here's the result of the wireless script: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10516365/

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo modprobe ath9k` and see if it will work.  If it doesn't include the results from `dmesg | tail`

If `sudo modprobe ath9k` works you can `echo ath9k | sudo tee -a /etc/modules` so it will work after a reboot

Comment: Results from dmesg|tail: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10527674/

Comment: The wireless problem might be caused by this  `FAT-fs (sda2): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.`

Answer (score 0):

This has plagued me when upgrading from stock kernels!
Here is what works for me.

Code:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Fingers Crossed!

Comment: The third command gave me an error saying: modprobe: FATAL: module wl not found.